What is the uses of Expected Value in this context?
I'm reading The Element of statistical learning: https://hastie.su.domains/ElemStatLearn/ and having question regarding this example on pages 23 and 24:
"Suppose we have 1000 training examples $x_{i}$
generated uniformly on $[-1,1]^{p}$. Assume that the true relationship between $X$ and $Y$ is
$$Y=f(X)=e^{-8||X||^{2}},$$
without any measurement error. We use the 1-nearest-neighbor rule to predict $y_{0}$ at the
test-point $x_{0}=0$. Denote the training set by $\mathcal{T}$. We can compute the expected prediction error at $x_{0}$ for our procedure, averaging over all such
samples of size 1000. Since the problem is deterministic, this is the mean squared error (MSE) for
estimating $f(0)$:
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\mathrm{MSE}(x_{0}) &= \mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}}[f(x_{0})-\hat{y}_{0}]^{2} \\ &=
\mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}}[\hat{y}_{0}-\mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}}(
\hat{y}_{0})]^{2}+[\mathrm{E}_{\mathcal{T}}(\hat{y}_{0})-f(x_{0})]^{2}\\ &=
\mathrm{Var}_{\mathcal{T}}(\hat{y}_{0})+\mathrm{Bias}^{2}(\hat{y }_{0}).\tag{2.25}
\end{alignat*}
"
As I have learned in my probability course, given a random variable $X$ with probability distribution $f(X)$, $E(X) = \int_{}^{}x f(x)dx$, so my question is:

What are the use of Expected Value here? Like what is the "random variable" and "distribution" here?
What is the meaning of the symbol "$\mathcal{T}$" in $E_{\mathcal{T}}$?  Does it means we are averaging over the training set (i.e the 1000 sample generated)?

P/s: I'm reading the book since I want to understand the mathematical aspect behinds machine learning algorithms. I'm have some background in calculus, algebra and statistic but I'm frequently encountering situation like this where I can not understand the use of the symbols and the meaning of the mathematic expression in the book. What can I do to improve this or should I find another book that is more suitable?

There are several random variables here:

$X$ is a random variable with uniform distribution on the sample space $[-1,1]^p$, the $p$-dimensional cube having edges of length $2$ which are parallel to the coordinate axes.
$Y$ is a random variable, dependent on $X$.  (You may recall some discussion of independent random variables and dependent random variables in your background statistics.)  Its distribution is unspecified, but computable from the definition of $f$ and the distribution of $X$.
The member $x_0$ of the 1000-member sample is a random variable.  Our experience in low dimensions might lead us to expect it is close to $0$ because we used the 1 nearest-neighbor method to pick the sample closest to $0$.  However, as $p$ gets bigger, our intuition may not be so accurate.
The deviation (prediction error) between $f(0)$ and $y_0 = f(x_0)$ is a random variable, dependent on the deviation between $0$ and $x_0$.  This is the variable whose mean-squared error is being studied.  Note that each 1000-member sample realization gives a different value for this deviation, so we would like to work over the space of all possible 1000-member samples (weighted by the probability of that sample being drawn from the distribution of $X$).  So, ...

"$E_\mathcal{T}$" is the expectation over the space of possible $\mathcal{T}$s: 1000-member samples from the distribution of $X$.  In
$$  E_\mathcal{T}[f(x_0)-\hat{y_0}]^2  $$
we seek the expectation of the square of the difference between $f(x_0)$ and the true value of $\hat{y_0} = f(0)$, over all possible $\mathcal{T}$s (weighted by their probability of being drawn from the distribution of $X$).

For large $p$, I do not think "we know" the nearest observation to $0$ is close to $0$.  In fact the point of the exercise is using the curse of dimensionality to say it is likely to be far enough away from $0$ to make the square of the bias in estimating $f(0)$ much larger than the variance of the estimate: even for $p=10$ you are likely to get an estimate $\hat y_0$ close to $0$ $\big($the lower bound for  $f(X)\big)$ due to this bias when in fact $f(0)=1$ (the highest possible value).

So the 1000 sample generated is not fixed but instead also random? In that case, what is the meaning of "Suppose we have 1000 training examples $x_{i}$
generated uniformly on $[-1,1]^{p}$", does it means that each $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ instance in the 1000 sample has equal distance?

@Henry: You are correct.  OP provided no explicit context to interpret the unintroduced variable $p$.  However, the source is clear that we are trying to recalibrate intuitions for higher dimensional sample spaces.

@alksdhalksjdb : It means: Repeat 1000 times: uniformly at random select a point in $[-1,1]^p$ (a vector of $p$ coordinates where each coordinate is in $[-1,1]$).  So the likelihood that $x_1$'s first coordinate is positive is $1/2$; the likelihood that $x_2$'s first coordinate is positive is $1/2$; ...; taken together, the likelihood that all ${x_i}_{i=1}^{1000}$ have positive first coordinate is $(1/2)^p$.  Note that for gigantic $p$, this probability is tiny, so it is unlikely that a sample realization, $\mathcal{T}$, has all 1000 points in that half-space.

@alksdhalksjdb each $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ instance does not have equal distance: they can be between $0$ and $2\sqrt{p}$ apart, but the expected value is slightly less than $\sqrt{\frac23p}$ with a standard deviation of about $0.5$.
